# App Indexing for Android

Tags: android, api, indexing, deep-linking

I have recently implemented the App indexing API from Google in an Android app but uncertain as to whether or not I need to add corresponding links to the corresponding website. My app supports http deep links and I have seen in some documentation that if http deep links are supported, no markup is necessary but on other Google documentation is states to add markup with uri's pointing to the app. Anyone know if there are any advantages to adding rel=alternate elements on the web site in addition to using the indexing API from the App? The app sends api data only when content is viewed as it is generated from our own API which sends the link dynamically from ours servers. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For App-Indexing, if you don't associate your app with your website using the Search Console, or when you want more granular control over which deep links get indexed in Search, you must link your app deep links either from the web pages markup or from the sitemap file.

There's more about the different options at https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/reference/deeplinks

Comment: Thanks Stan, so essentially all links from the sub domain referenced in the intent in the android manifest will be indexed as long as the website is associated with the app but we can't prevent individual links from being indexed at that point?

Comment: Hi Jaz, you can prevent individual links from being indexed by inserting them in the [noindex.xml] file. You can find more information on how to do that in here - https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app

Hope this helps.